# Filtering elements using data attributes and input?

Tags: jquery, filter, custom-data-attribute

I am using this particular theme with my project and currently working with the chat functionality.

[Smart Admin Theme](https://bootstraphunter.com/smartadmin-product.php)

The Chat API beta has an input box which can basically be used to filter users but is just a dummy. I have given it an id of `chat-filter` and using this code in jquery to filter users in the chat:

```
$('#chat-filter').on('input', null, null, function(e){
    $('.display-users a').filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('chatFname') != $('#chat-filter').val();
    }).hide();
});
```

On change of the input field I am selecting all the users in the chat and filtering them via the custom function. I am just trying to filter it by the `chatFname` data attribute now but I am not sure what I am doing wrong and it is not working.

But really what I want is to filter users according to all data attributes ie match all the data attributes to the input so that if somebody wants to filter a user by their role, that works too. What am I doing wrong and how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using `'keyup'` or `'keypress'`, or `'change'` instead of `'input'`?

Also, you should call `show()` on the other elements, otherwise, if they were hidden by a previous input, they will never show again.

```
$('#chat-filter').on('keyup', function(e){
    var filterValue = $('#chat-filter').val();
    $('.display-users a').show()
    .filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('chatFname') != filterValue;
    }).hide();
});
```

Then, you can add other checks:

```
$('#chat-filter').on('keyup', function(e){
    //toLowerCase() so it is case insensitive
    var filterValue = $('#chat-filter').val().toLowerCase();
    $('.display-users a').show()
    .filter(function(){
        //looks for filterValue inside chatFname using String.indexOf
        //toLowerCase() so it is case insensitive
        if ($(this).data('chatFname').toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) !== -1) {
            return false;
        }
        //filter returns list of roles that contain the filterValue string
        //then we test length to check whether we found any roles
        //again, toLowerCase() so it is case insensitive
        if ($(this).data('chatRoles').filter(function (role) { return role.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) !== -1; } ).length) {
            return false;
        }
        [...]
        return true;
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: Not working. Same as before. As soon as I start tying, all users are hidden

Comment: @Rohan: you need to look inside the string using ``indexOf`` instead of using ``===``. I edited my answer.

Comment: Wow. This works. Thank you so much. Although I don't understand it completely, I will dig into this. Just one small thing that it is case sensitive meaning I have to match the first name exactly with the first character uppercase. Any idea to make it case insensitive.

Comment: @Rohan: I edited my answer to make it case insensitive and to describe what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using regular expressions to match the filtering elements

```
$('#filter').keyup(function () {

            var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
            $('.searchable tr').hide();
            $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
                return rex.test($(this).attr("data-chatFname"));
            }).show();

        })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52aK9/790/

Comment: That's a good solution if he wants to handle his input value as a regex. I'm not sure he wants that behavior.